# Error in defining Variables

Tags: linux, command-line, variable, variable-substitution

I am trying to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39729938/replace-paragraph-in-text) to replace a multiline text.

But to do that I want to put some text like below into a variable.

```dataview
TABLE WITHOUT ID page-no as no, link(file.name, topic) as name
                                  WHERE back-to = this.file.link
                        SORT file.name asc
                                    SORT page-no asc
```

I tried the following command:

````bash
original="```dataview\nTABLE WITHOUT ID page-no as no, link(file.name, topic) as name\nWHERE back-to = this.file.link\nSORT file.name asc\nSORT page-no asc\n```"
````

But I am getting this error:

```bash
bash: command substitution: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('                                  bash: command substitution: line 1: `dataview\nTABLE WITHOUT ID page-no as no, link(file.name, topic) as name\nWHERE back-to = this.file.link\nSORT file.name asc\nSORT page-no asc\n'
```

How to do it right...

Answer (score 1):

From `man bash` (emphasis mine):

> Enclosing  characters  in  double quotes preserves the literal
> value of    all characters within the quotes, **with the exception of** $,
> `,  ,  and,    when history expansion is enabled, !.

Since the backquotes are not preserved literally, the shell is parsing them as command substitutions - you need single quotes here, which preserve the literal value of all characters.

OTOH, backslash escapes like `\n` are *not* treated specially in singel- or double-quoted strings - if you want newlines you can include them literally. So:

````
original='```dataview
  TABLE WITHOUT ID page-no as no, link(file.name, topic) as name
  WHERE back-to = this.file.link
  SORT file.name asc
  SORT page-no asc
  ```'

$ echo "$original"
```dataview
  TABLE WITHOUT ID page-no as no, link(file.name, topic) as name
  WHERE back-to = this.file.link
  SORT file.name asc
  SORT page-no asc
  ```
````

If you really want to use `\n`, you can do so in bash using [ANSI C quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html),

````
original=$'```dataview\nTABLE WITHOUT ID page-no as no, link(file.name, topic) as name\nWHERE back-to = this.file.link\nSORT file.name asc\nSORT page-no asc\n```'
````

or use the shell's built-in `printf` function:

````
printf -v original '```dataview\nTABLE WITHOUT ID page-no as no, link(file.name, topic) as name\nWHERE back-to = this.file.link\nSORT file.name asc\nSORT page-no asc\n```'
````

but IMHO these are harder to read.

Comment: It is not producing the newline. It just result in a single line.

Comment: @zakadmin Did you use `echo "$original"` with double quotes?

Comment: Sorry my Mistake. Thanks